# IntelliJ: How to prompt for type when creating a generic instance?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

If I have a generic class, e.g.

```
public class Action<T> {}
```

…and I want to create an instance of `Action<String>`,

I can start typing `new Act…` then hit `<ctrl>+<space>` to show the autocomplete suggestions.

When I select a suggestion, IntelliJ attempts to infer the generic type from the context. When there is useful context, that's great, but often I end up with `Action<Object>`.

Is there a way to manually specify the type when using auto complete?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when there is not enough context, you can fake it by declaring a temporary variable. Type something like:

```
Action<String> x =
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> at the end of the line. It will expand to a the desired result. Then you can use the variable `x` in the actual expression and immediately inline it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. The variable will be removed and its usage will be replaced by the expression.